# Trying to add text and color in an HTML and CSS coded page

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS as i am learning these things. I tried to write a very simple code with the help of the above. when i do it in fiddle it shows only the colored bars and when I am trying it in Sublime Text editor then it is showing text ONLY without any colored bars. here is the link to my code

https://jsfiddle.net/recklesswish/aw330go1/

```css
    
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css")
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}   
body {
     font-family: 'Open Sans';

}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


div#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin;left:15px;
}


.logo a {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #fff;
}

.logo a span {
    font-weight: 300;
}

div#container {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #010101;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header"> 
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">Xero<span>Source</span></a>
   </div>
 </div> 
 <div id="container">
   <div class="sidebar">
     klskdn
   </div>
   <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is your css file properly loaded locally? I suspect not, since you wrote `<linl rel="stylesheet"` instead of `<link rel="stylesheet"`.

Comment: thank you. i did . It still is not working on fiddle. it is just showing me the colored bars. that's all.

Comment: The text is there, just change the colour of it and you'll see it

Comment: Can you show the screenshot that defines the exact result you want. Question is not clear

Comment: both Xero logo and klskden are getting printed on screen Xeros color is white and Klskden's color is black so you are not able to see them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, you need to fix

```
<linl rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />
```

and fix your CSS markup in regards to

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin;left:15px;
}
```

to

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

Next, the reason why you are not seeing any text and just a color bar for   .sidebar is because the text is black. You need to add in the color property for that class or move it using margin.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #010101;
    float: left;
    color:#fff; /* change to whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. i got sorted it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a first point you have an error:

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin;left:15px;
}
```

should be

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

You're ending your line too early with the `;` typo and likely messing up the rest of your document. jsFiddle is probably overlooking this error. Try changing it and loading it locally and seeing if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure the HTML links to your CSS, current spelling mistake on 'linl rel' needs to be 'link rel'

Second you need to change the colour of the text on the .logo a class in global.css, change to #000; and you will see the text, it is also worth adding a p tag around the random text in the container div and add a p tag to the css changing the color to white (#fff;) and you will get that text to display.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/recklesswish/aw330go1/ here i got the text as i changed the text color. thank you for making my errors correct for me. I really am asking so basic things but now i am getting the text but below the red bar. where as the text should come inside the red bar.

Comment: If you take out the Float: Left; in the logo class do you see what you want?

Comment: Yes i got it.. Thanks alot for helping me out. now would make other changes and will add more style to make is interactive. hope will not get any other error. or else would ask for your help. thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have made a page now with different styles and now want to add images dynamically. how to do that could you please tell me. As i am not getting it any other where. Thank you in advance.    https://jsfiddle.net/recklesswish/aw330go1/2/

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: did you see my code ?? This is just a simple code that i used to make a webpage. now my main motive is to use the web service to fetch the news from any of the particular news website. which is little beyond out of my reach as of now. but what i want is suppose i have bunch of images with me and the moment i click on any image it should get changed to another picture and so on.

Comment: Now i will give you clear concept what what exactly i want. https://jsfiddle.net/recklesswish/aw330go1/3/ here is my code in fiddle and i there in the list i have "Images" so on the click of the images. i want one picture on the page at a time and then as i click on next i should get next image and so on. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<style>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css")
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}   
body {
     font-family: 'Open Sans';
         color:green;  
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


div#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.logo a {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: blue;
}

.logo a span {

    font-weight: 300;
}

div#container {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #010101;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"> 
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">Xero<span>Source</span></a>
   </div>
 </div> 
 <div id="container">
   <div class="sidebar">
     klskdn
   </div>
   <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

try this in local